# undefined method `send_request' for #<Net::SSH::Connection::Channel:0x0000000163d6d8> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

Does anybody know what is the corresponding command in V2 version of ssh .vs. V1's:

chan.send_request "shell", nil, true

Thanks!
  Dan

Answer (score 0):

It is [`send_channel_request`](http://net-ssh.github.com/net-ssh/classes/Net/SSH/Connection/Channel.html#M000071).

For example, to test your github connection in Ruby:

```
Net::SSH.start("github.com", "git", {}) do |session|
  session.open_channel do |channel|

    channel.on_extended_data do |ch, type, data|
      next unless type == 1
      warn data
    end

    channel.send_channel_request "shell"
  end

  session.loop
end
```

The linked doc also gives an example of handling success/failure (the `true` argument and `on_success`/`on_failure` you passed in v1 are handled differently in v2)